# Xamarin.Forms Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror' when trying to create MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am having problems with my Xamarin.Forms not wanting to load anymore, it keeps giving me the error message

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'.
```

My code ATM is

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hoofdstuk04"
             x:Class="Hoofdstuk04.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Master">
            <StackLayout>
                <!-- Click event method nog toevoegen -->
                <Button Text="RandomColorPage"></Button>
                <Button Text="CarouselPage"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <!--<local:ImageViewerPage />-->
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error? The only thing I changed was the inheritance of the MainPage in the code from **ContentPage** to **MasterDetailPage**

Answer (score 0):

Workaround in order to prevent "Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror'":

- Change build type to **"Release"** as opposed to **"Debug"**