# iOS push notification not received to physical device from Azure

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications

I've created a sample app for testing push notifications on iOS. I'm running Visual Studio 2019 on a PC, which is connected over a local network to a MAC. An iPhone is connected to the MAC via lightning cable. As the title suggests, ReceivedRemoteNotification method is never called when I Test Send from Azure. Azure informs me that the test message was sent successfully.

I've followed this guide multiple times and rigorously:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is called so it appears that the app successfully registers for push notifications. I also get the permission request on the physical device, which I accept. However I have noticed that when I hover over 'Hub' inside this method, under the class handle it gives an error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'."

however I'm not sure if this is actually related at all to my problem. I can't find anything online aside from this link which only suggests that a workaround to that error is to run in release as opposed to debug.

[Xamarin.Forms Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.TypeMirror' when trying to create MasterDetailPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855130/xamarin-forms-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-runtimetype-to-type-mono-d)

Sample code straight from the microsoft guide I linked above:

```
namespace PushNotifTestApp.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        private SBNotificationHub Hub { get; set; }

        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                                        (granted, error) => InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications));
            }
            else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                        new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
            }


            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

            Hub.UnregisterAll(deviceToken, (error) => {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
                    return;
                }

                NSSet tags = null; // create tags if you want
                Hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterNative error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                });
            });
        }

        public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
        }

        void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
        {
            // Check to see if the dictionary has the aps key.  This is the notification payload you would have sent
            if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
            {
                //Get the aps dictionary
                NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

                string alert = string.Empty;

                //Extract the alert text
                // NOTE: If you're using the simple alert by just specifying
                // "  aps:{alert:"alert msg here"}  ", this will work fine.
                // But if you're using a complex alert with Localization keys, etc.,
                // your "alert" object from the aps dictionary will be another NSDictionary.
                // Basically the JSON gets dumped right into a NSDictionary,
                // so keep that in mind.
                if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                    alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();

                //If this came from the ReceivedRemoteNotification while the app was running,
                // we of course need to manually process things like the sound, badge, and alert.
                if (!fromFinishedLaunching)
                {
                    //Manually show an alert
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alert))
                    {
                        var myAlert = UIAlertController.Create("Notification", alert, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                        myAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(myAlert, true, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the method `ReceivedRemoteNotification` been called when app in foreground ? You could post the issue to https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin/issues

Comment: Hi Lucas, no it isn't called at all. Okay I will look to post my issue on Github thank you

Comment: I have now done this https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin/issues/26